# Can't initialize StdSchedulerFactory in Quartz dot net

Tags: c#, quartz-scheduler, quartz.net

I am getting below error while initializing StdSchedulerFactory in Quartz.net

```
The type initializer for 'Quartz.Impl.StdSchedulerFactory' threw an exception
{"Could not load file or assembly 'Common.Logging, Version=3.3.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=af08829b84f0328e' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.":"Common.Logging, Version=3.3.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=af08829b84f0328e"}
fusionlog: === Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: DisplayName = Common.Logging, Version=3.3.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=af08829b84f0328e
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///  
LOG: Initial PrivatePath =  
Calling assembly : Quartz, Version=2.6.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=f6b8c98a402cc8a4.
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file:  d\web.config
LOG: Using host configuration file: C:\Users\ \Documents\IISExpress\config\aspnet.config
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Post-policy reference: Common.Logging, Version=3.3.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=af08829b84f0328e
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/Temporary ASP.NET Files/root/f3308e15/e6cfbeeb/Common.Logging.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/Temporary ASP.NET Files/root/f3308e15/e6cfbeeb/Common.Logging/Common.Logging.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:/// bin/Common.Logging.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:// SCS.Presentation.Web/bin/Common.Logging/Common.Logging.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/Temporary ASP.NET Files/root/f3308e15/e6cfbeeb/Common.Logging.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/Temporary ASP.NET Files/root/f3308e15/e6cfbeeb/Common.Logging/Common.Logging.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:/// /bin/Common.Logging.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:/// SCS.Presentation.Web/bin/Common.Logging/Common.Logging.EXE.
```

The same code was working before some time, all of sudden it started throwing this exception. 
Please find below my code,

```
var id = queryParams.Schedule.ScheduleId.ToString();
                var config = (NameValueCollection)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("quartz");
                // First we must get a reference to a scheduler
                ISchedulerFactory sf = new StdSchedulerFactory(config);
                IScheduler scheduler = sf.GetScheduler();

                ITrigger trigger;
                IJobDetail job = JobBuilder.Create<ScheduleJob>()
                 .WithIdentity(id)
                 .Build();
```

I am getting error on this line

```
 ISchedulerFactory sf = new StdSchedulerFactory(config);
```

Comment: Did you reference Quartz.net through its nuget package?

Comment: Do you have `Common.Logging` in your project references?

Comment: Yes, I referenced Quartz.net through its nuget package and I have Common.Logging in your project references.

Comment: Most People don't want to schedule there STDs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common problem with quartz. You need to add a binding redirect to your config for `Common.Logging` and `Common.Logging.Core`. Just add this to your config, that quartz can find the Logging assemblies.

```
<runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="Common.Logging.Core" publicKeyToken="af08829b84f0328e" culture="neutral" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.4.1.0" newVersion="3.4.1.0" />
        </dependentAssembly>
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="Common.Logging" publicKeyToken="af08829b84f0328e" culture="neutral" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.4.1.0" newVersion="3.4.1.0" />
        </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```

You need to exchange the `newVersion="3.4.1.0"` to the version you have installed for both assemblies.